# Migration of Virtual Machines using SCVMM error 1612

Tags: hyper-v, migration, virtual-machines, cloning, scvmm

The situation is as follows: I have installed SCVMM on our Windows Server 2008. I can create VMs fine, use them, etc. Everything works fine with the VMs themselves. However, if I decide to do the following: Migration of an existing VM, Cloning an existing VM or creating a new VM based on an existing VM's VHD, the SCVMM console loses connection with an error 1612 message and has to start, thus failing the job.

When the console restarts, the job log indicates that the operation was aborted because the console restarted (Error 1700), so that doesn't really help.

I search a lot but I still can't find anything related to this issue. Has anyone encountered the same problem? Or does anyone have a solution or other information that could help me solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Philippe-

Take a look at the following KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;969269

Comment: Thanks, that pretty much resumed my problem. I will try those solutions.